# Jquery .removeClass function isn't working

Tags: jquery, css, removeclass

I'm trying to add a button to a slide in menu that will close it on click.

You can see a demo [here.](http://le1dev.co.uk/saferfoodhandler9/admin.html) The menu button appears at 960px browser width. I have added a `close-menu` link to the top of the menu, and used this code to make that link remove the `menu-open` class from the nav, which in theory, should close the menu.

```
$('.close-menu').click(function() {
      $("#adminmobmenu").removeClass("menu-open");
});
```

My issue is that this code isn't really doing anything, and I'm not sure why.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `Cannot read property 'style' of null` in console..

Comment: You need to add the script in a dom ready handler, you have placed the script before the element is added to the dom

Comment: Do you have your jQuery included?

Comment: Seems that the problem is here : " document.getElementById('mobile-courses-menu').style.display = 'none'; " 
Are you sure "#mobile-courses-menu" exists ?

Answer (score 0):

Your script is not inside the document.ready function[image]